# `git diff` equivalent of `git log --grep` (git log squash or git diff multiple commits)

Tags: git

Consider `git log --grep foo`. This will return all commits where the commit message contains 'foo'.

`git log --grep foo -p` will show all of the patches separately.

How can I view a single diff of the combined/squashed version of those patches?

Comment: I'm not sure that's a well-defined operation. What if those patches where at different parts of the history, in different branches, or simply conflicting with each other?

Comment: If they're all contiguous in one branch, then it would at least be well defined, but otherwise I don't see how you could define this operation in a general way.

Comment: The best option I can come up with so far is to branch off from the common ancestor and cherry-pick the relevant commits, but it seems a bit heavyweight having to create a branch for this.

Comment: Well, branches are super cheap, really, so that doesn't seem heavyweight to me at all. Create a temporary branch and discard that branch when you're done. In fact, you've already got half the design for a script to automate what you're talking about. The snag will be dealing with conflicts... That part's going to be heavy weight on the user if it's just to look at that diff!

Answer (score 0):

As [joanis implied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73071078/git-diff-equivalent-of-git-log-grep-git-log-squash-or-git-diff-multiple-c#comment129057216_73071078) in [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73071078/git-diff-equivalent-of-git-log-grep-git-log-squash-or-git-diff-multiple-c#comment129057264_73071078), you can't do that.  The reason is simple enough: the snapshot you'd get by combining those commits into one big patch *does not exist until you combine those commits into one big patch*.

Remember, every Git commit represents a *full snapshot* of the entire source tree as of the time the snapshot was made.  There are no diffs here.  To produce a diff from "snapshot a123456 made by A U Thor <thor@example.com>" to "snapshot b789abc made by Lex Luthor <lex@example.com>", snapshot `b789abc` has to exist in the first place.

You've instead taken 2N snapshots—the commits you got from `git log --grep`, and their parents—and turned these into N separate diffs, each of which apply to a different parent.  You must now somehow pick one "super-parent" starting point, combine all N diffs, and apply the combined diffs to that "super-parent" starting point.  That gives you starting and ending snapshots, which you can now diff.

Alternatively, you can write some software to combine all N diffs, but Git does not contain such software.  Git does contain software that can combine *two* diffs: that's `git merge`.  However, if the diffs *conflict*, the combination process generally stops in the middle and needs your help.  In Git's case, the two diffs that are to be combined *must apply to a single parent snapshot*.  Your case has N diffs, each of which apply to a *different* parent snapshot.

(Side question: are Thor and Luthor related?  If so, how?)